# SQL Insert into table A from table B based off table C

Tags: sql, insert, db2

I have an empty table that I would like to fill with rows from a second table, based off a third table, Ill call them A,B,C respectively.

Table C has ID numbers that match ID numbers for rows in Table B. For every ID in table C, I want to add the corresponding row from table B into Table A.

This is what I have, and I am getting an error saying that I cannot use the last statement.

```
INSERT INTO TABLEA              
  SELECT * FROM TABLEB     
  WHERE ID FROM TABLEB = ID FROM TABLEC;

DSNT408I SQLCODE = -199, ERROR:  ILLEGAL USE OF KEYWORD FROM.  TOKEN ( . AT  
         MICROSECONDS MICROSECOND SECONDS SECOND MINUTES MINUTE WAS EXPECTED 
DSNT418I SQLSTATE   = 42601 SQLSTATE RETURN CODE
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO TableA
    SELECT B.*
      FROM TableB AS B
      JOIN TableC AS C ON B.ID = C.ID
```

Or possibly that will give you too many duplicates (if there are multiple rows in C that match a given row in B), in which case you might need:

```
INSERT INTO TableA
    SELECT B.*
      FROM TableB AS B
     WHERE B.ID IN (SELECT C.ID FROM TableC AS C)
```

Or:

```
INSERT INTO TableA
    SELECT DISTINCT B.*
      FROM TableB AS B
      JOIN TableC AS C ON B.ID = C.ID
```

Both of those give you one row in A for each row in B that matches one or more rows in C.

---

> How would I add a `WHEN` clause to this? Let's say Table C has another column called VALUE, and I want to add all the ID numbers that have a value of 'x' or greater. How would I do that, I tried adding `JOIN TableC AS C ON B.ID = C.ID AND C.VALUE > 5` but I still got all the values from TABLE C.

Working with the first query (fixing the others being left as an 'exercise for the reader'), then what I think you should be doing is just:

```
INSERT INTO TableA
    SELECT B.*
      FROM TableB AS B
      JOIN TableC AS C ON B.ID = C.ID
     WHERE C.Value > 5
```

The optimizer should translate that to an equivalent expression:

```
INSERT INTO TableA
    SELECT B.*
      FROM TableB AS B
      JOIN TableC AS C ON B.ID = C.ID AND C.Value > 5
```

I'm not clear from your comment whether you somehow added a second reference to TableC in the one query, or you modified your query as shown in this second example.  If you were not using LEFT JOIN anywhere, then adding the `AND C.Value > 5` term to the ON clause or as a WHERE clause should have yielded the correct data.

When debugging this sort of problem, it is worth noting that this INSERT statement has a perfectly good SELECT statement in it that you can run on its own to review what is going to be added to TableA.  You might want to augment the select-list to include (at least) `C.ID` and `C.Value` just to make sure nothing is going haywire.

Comment: How would I add a WHEN clause to this? Let's say Table C has another column called VALUE, and I want to add all the ID numbers that have a value of 'x' or greater. How would I do that, I tried adding 

      `JOIN TableC AS C ON B.ID = C.ID AND C.VALUE > 5` but I still got all the values from TABLE C

Comment: Great, I got it to work. I wasn't paying attention to what was already in my table before I started adding other rows. Thanks a lot for the clarification and the help!